# Random Audio Over Random Interval In Unity

Tags: c#, android, audio, unity-game-engine

Basically, I am making an Unity game. I need some audio clips to cycle randomly at random interval and play. As for right now, I have written a script that should do that but I am having issues. Here is the script below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] private AudioClip[] clips;
private int clipIndex;
private AudioSource audio;
private bool audioPlaying = false;

void Start()
{
    audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlaySound());

}

IEnumerator PlaySound()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(10f, 20f));
    audioPlaying = false;
    if (!audioPlaying)
    {
        clipIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length - 1);
        audioPlaying = true;
        audio.PlayOneShot(clips[clipIndex], 1f);
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(10f, 20f));
}
}
```

Basically, when debugging, I find that audioPlaying remains true, and that clipIndex constantly cycles through the indices. Eventually all the sounds just play non-stop and make a large humming noise. My problem is the audioPlaying is not disabled, and the wait time is not necessarily working as a result. Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because every frame you have something that looks like such:

```
audioPlaying = false;
if (!audioPlaying)
{
    audioPlaying = true;
}
```

do you see the problem? might as well have this:

```
if (true)
{
    audioPlaying = true;
}
```

anyways, you can try:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlaySound());
}

IEnumerator PlaySound()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(10f, 20f));

    clipIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length - 1);
    audio.PlayOneShot(clips[clipIndex], 1f);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clips[clipIndex].length);
    StartCoroutine(PlaySound());
}
```

Comment: I still have the same issue with this. When I debug, I notice that the index changes every frame still, without waiting for the previous clip to end (as done in yield return new WaitForSeconds(clips[clipIndex].Length); ). In this case, I think it is because, we never manage audioPlaying, and it is always set to false by default. Where would you assign it?

Comment: Yea i left that in by mistake, try now. And notice its in the `Start()` method now, not `Update()` as it calls itself now.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic! Thanks for clearing it up! It now works near perfectly like I wanted it!

Answer (score 3):

Your working wrong calling every Update to the coroutine and setting to false audioplaying and playing a new sound.
Try this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] private AudioClip[] clips;
private int clipIndex;
private AudioSource audio;
private bool audioPlaying = false;

void Start()
{
    audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
void Update()
    {

        if (!audio.isPlaying) 
        {

            clipIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length - 1);
            audio.clip = clips[clipIndex];
            audio.PlayDelayed(Random.Range(10f, 20f));
            Debug.Log("Nothing playing, we set new audio to " + audio.clip.name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really close to what I did initially, but I noticed that audio.isPlaying does not work because we never assign the clip to the AudioSource but instead just play a clip. When I assigned the clip to the AudioSource, there was a whole another set of problems such as looping audio, and the same problems from before.

Comment: Ok , i try to fix your code.
On this case use the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] clips;
    private int clipIndex;
    private AudioSource audio;
    private bool audioPlaying = false;

    void Start()
    {
        audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (!audio.isPlaying) 
        {
            clipIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length - 1);
            audio.clip = clips[clipIndex];
            audio.PlayDelayed(Random.Range(20f, 50f));
            Debug.Log("Nothing playing, we set new audio to " + audio.clip.name);
        }
    }
}
```